# Может ли надел земли принадлежать домишке?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов

> Но вот дорога начинает сначала неожиданно петлять, потом резко
>   устремляется вверх, и то тут, то там из-за вековых деревьев
>   выглядывают весёлые – разноцветные! – древние **домишки**, утопающие в
>   розовых кустах. **У каждого из них свой надел земли, спускающейся
>   террасами**, непременный оливковый сад и спутник его – виноградник,
>   облака зелени, в тени которых прячутся огороды и строгими охранниками
>   высятся могучие кипарисы…

Может, как-то иначе можно прочитать?

И как быть с моментом перехода от виноградника к облакам зелени, - запятая смущает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Но вот дорога начинает сначала неожиданно петлять, потом резко устремляется вверх, и то тут, то там из-за вековых деревьев выглядывают  **весёлые (разноцветные!) старинные домики, утопающие в розовых кустах.**

У каждого  из них свой участок земли — сплошное облако зелени, террасами спускающееся по склону.  Непременный оливковый сад и спутник его — виноградник,  в тени  которых прячутся огороды, а рядом строгими охранниками высятся могучие кипарисы…

Пояснение

1) Сочетание *веселые древние домишки* вызывает сомнение.

2) Я посмотрела общую картину (зеленый массив как шелковый покров, наброшенный на острые серые скалы; ткань его играет сотнями оттенков).  Нужно сохранить описание этой цветовой гаммы: переход от розового цвета к зеленому.

3) Также ***в тени которых*** должно стоять после садов и виноградников.

Comment: согласен с вами: лучше написать: веселые, разноцветные древнии. Поскольку прилагательные "веселые и разноцветные сближаются общим признаком. Да и само сочетание в целом, как вы верно заметили, тоже вызывает сомнение.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за поддержку. Трудный  текст, никак не редактируется.  Нужно, чтобы пейзаж с нужными красками получился. Домишки,  домики?

Comment: Шаронушко, стока многа всиво (варьянтов), што ЛОшку будит вручадь аффтар.

Comment: Разные картинки получаются при сочетании слов древний/старинный и домик/домишко. Старинные домики - это нечто аккуратное, не очень живописное. Древние домишки -  это может восприниматься как  "ветхие, запущенные домишки", негативная оценка.  Но может звучать и положительно, образно-художественно. Главное, чтобы читатель это услышал.

Comment: Рисую: "Но вот дорога начинает сначала неожиданно петлять, потом резко устремляется вверх, и то тут, то там из-за вековых деревьев выглядывают весёлые (разноцветные!) древние домишки, утопающие в розовых кустах. При каждом коттеджике (МОЖНО? Я ВЛЕЗЛА С КОТТЕДЖИКОМ? А ХОЧЕШЬ - ВИЛЛОЧКУ?) – свой надел земли, спускающейся террасами, где непременный крошечный сад и спутник его – виноградник, вокруг же – настоящие облака зелени, в тени которых прячутся огороды, а могучие кипарисы высятся над ними строгими охранниками…"

Answer (score 2):

Предлог "у" можно трактовать как "около/вблизи", но для однозначности прочтения с первого раза (поначалу может казаться, что землёй наделили дом, а не хозяина) лучше заменить на "при (каждом)". Не очень складно "надел спускающейся земли".

Answer (score 2):

Но вот дорога начинает сначала неожиданно петлять, потом резко устремляется вверх, и то тут, то там из-за вековых деревьев выглядывают весёлые – разноцветные! – утопающие в розовых кустах древние домишки. При каждом свой надел земли, спускающейся террасами, непременные оливковый сад и виноградник — облака зелени, в тени которых прячутся огороды. Строгими охранниками высятся могучие кипарисы…

Может быть, так?
*...древние домишки, утопающие в розовых кустах. У каждого из них...* — возникает ощущение, что земля принадлежит розовым кустам.
*...древние домишки. При каждом свой надел земли…* — "из них" мне показалось лишним.
Сомнения: могучие кипарисы не могут **выситься в тени** оливковых садов и виноградников. Они, думаю, **возвышаются над** тенью.

Comment: Римуль, спасибо за возвышение внутри тени. )))

Answer (score 1):

...древние домишки, утопающие в розах; от каждого тянутся вниз сходящие террасами наделы земли: непременно с оливковыми садами и их спутниками — виноградниками и с облаками зелени, где в тени прячутся огороды, где строгими охранниками высятся могучие кипарисы…

Comment: Я думаю (как читатель), что оливковый сад и спутник его – виноградник, вкупе с ещё какой-нито, но уже менее значительной растительностью, и образуют етии "облака зелени"... Если б перед виноградником не было тире, я бы поставила его перед облаками.

Answer (score 0):

Подле каждого — свой надел земли...

Comment: Знак Тире — на клаве: alt + 151.